# If $f$ is submersion of class $C^1$, then is open and non-injective.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> If $f:A \subset \mathbb R^{n+p} \to  \mathbb R^p$ is a $C^1$-submersion in the open $A$, and $n>0$, then $f$ is open and non-injective.

My attempt, to show that $f$ is open: Consider $F:A \subset \mathbb R^{n+p} \to  \mathbb R^{n+p}$ with $F(r,s)=(r,f(r,s))$ which $\det DF(r,s)\neq 0$, apply the inverse function theorem, and so I managed to show that $W \subset A $ open, $$f(W)=P_{2}F\circ F(W)= P_{2}F(Z)$$
is open, and I still have not been able to solve why it is injective, someone could help me.

Comment: $F$ is invertible (in some small neighbourhood) and $f = \text{pr}_2\circ F$. THis means $\text{pr}_2 = f \circ F^{-1}$. If $f$ was injective, then $f\circ F^{-1}$ being the composition of two injective maps is injective. But $\text{pr}_2$ is clearly not an injective map. By the way, you need to be more careful with your proof, because you've never defined what $W$.

Comment: given $(r,s) \in A$,$W$ is the open that results from applying the inverse function theorem on $F$.Where $(r,s) \in W$ and $F(W)=Z$ open of $\mathbb R^{n+p}$